# How to scale svg in x and y axis from a object tag?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

In my html file, I have a svg loaded through a object tag. I want to scale it in the x and y axis but it is not working. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Animate</title>
        <style>
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <object data="images/steve/steve.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="steve" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

        <script>

            var steve = document.getElementById("steve");

            steve.addEventListener("load", function() {

                var svgDoc = steve.contentDocument; 


                //steve.setAttribute('transform','scale(1.0 2.0)');   // this does not work

            },false);
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to set a transform on an element within the svgDoc i.e. via svgDoc.getElementById("whatever"), not on the object element. Having said that, if you want to scale everything it would be easiest to set the object element height and width to 200%

Answer (score 0):

put the svg element in a div and scale that instead. Also, make sure you set width and height to 100% on the svg element itself within "steve.svg" so that it scales with the element. You can do this by opening steve.svg in a text editor and adding `width="100%" height="100%"` to the `<svg></svg>` tags

```
<div id="steve-container">
    <object data="images/steve/steve.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="steve" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>
```

then just set the css style on steve-container to the desired size